# Write a function that given a list of non negative integers, arranges them such that they form the largest possible number

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections

## My Problem

I have the following spec:

> Write a function that given a list of non negative integers, arranges them such that they form the largest possible number. For example, given [50, 2, 1, 9], the largest formed number is 95021.

## My Results

I have taken a stab at a solution to the problem, but it fails. For example, given the input [90,91,89,999] the result of this code is [909199989], but it should have been [999919089].

## A Description of My Algorithm

In simple words it is a reverse of radix sort.

Steps
1)  Based on the values create buckets.
2)  Each bucket has list of elements.
3)  Sort the list in each bucket.
4)  Display the result in the reverse order.

## My code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseMaxPossibleNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 50, 2, 1, 9 };
        int len = a.length;
        String ch = "";
        List<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> list_map = new ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ch = "" + a[i];
            String str = "";
            ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                str = "" + a[j];
                if (ch.charAt(0) == str.charAt(0)) {
                    arraylist.add(str);
                    Collections.sort(arraylist);
                    map.put("" + ch.charAt(0), arraylist);
                }
            }
        }
        list_map.add(map);
        String str = "";
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            str = map.get(key) + str;

        }
        str = str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just join them in reverse alphabetical order? Is implementing the sorting algorithm part of the assignment, or can you use a library function for that part and just have to figure out how to apply it?

Comment: @tobias_k that wont work for numbers with a different amount of digits. ie 10, 9 is bigger as 910

Comment: Using Collections.sort() i am sorting the list inside every map.

Comment: @flkes 9 and 10 belongs to different buckets, so no need to sort.

Comment: Yes I agree, Please help me to correct the code.

Comment: @tobias_k Actually, lexicographic (what you call "alphabetical") works just fine because "9" comes before "90".

Comment: @JimGarrison Whops, you are right. Must have accidentally reversed the sort. But that still won't work. Consider numbers `4, 45`; here `45` should come before `4`; but for `4, 43`, `4` should come first.

Comment: @JimGarrison however "91" comes before "92", and "92" should be preferred.

Comment: It looks like in each map i have to use radix sort to fix the bug?

Comment: @tobias_k `4` should only come before `43` when there's another digit available greater than `3` to append to it :-(

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Well, there is: The `4` from `43`! You can either form `434` or `443`.

Comment: I've downvoted this question for the following reasons: (1) it asks for "suggestions" for how to improve space and time complexity without explaining what the current complexity is or what it needs to be, and (2) the core question is actually "My code has bugs please correct the code" which is a classic example of a bad question. What are the bugs, in detail?

Comment: @DavidS Fair point. I have made a partial edit that addresses your concerns. I hope it can be fleshed out to make this a good question.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, the numbers need to be ordered in a certain way to form the maximum possible number. Consider this logic:

- Take any 2 numbers `a` and `b`
- If `ab` is bigger than `ba` then `a` should come before `b`. Right?

  - Where `ab` is `a` and `b` concatenated, so if `a = 4` and `b = 43` then `ab` is `443` and `ba` is `434`

You could implement this in a custom comparator, and pass it to `Collections.sort`, like this:

```
public String maxNumber(int[] numbers) {
    // convert int[] -> List<String>
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(numbers.length);
    for (int num : numbers) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(num));
    }

    // sort using custom comparator
    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> (o2 + o1).compareTo(o1 + o2));

    // join sorted items, forming max possible number
    return String.join("", list);
}
```

Here is basically the same code using Java 8: (thanks [@marcospereira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4600/marcospereira)!)

```
public String maxNumber(Integer ... numbers) {
    return Stream.of(numbers)
            .filter(n -> n >= 0)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .sorted((s1, s2) -> (s2 + s1).compareTo(s1 + s2))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: Done. I've also add a filter to avoid negative numbers.

Comment: @marcospereira oh that's beautiful, thank you! (added credits)

Answer (score 1):

Here is realization on JS

https://jsfiddle.net/b6r81jv9/

```
let input = [
  {test: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], res: "87654321"},
  {test: [50, 2, 1, 9], res: "95021"},
  {test: [1, 19], res: "191"},
  {test: [9, 90], res: "990"},
  {test: [9, 90, 900], res: "990900"},
  {test: [9, 909, 9909, 999], res: "99999909909"}
];
function big_number_simplified(arr) {
    return [...arr].sort((a, b) => b.toString() + a > a.toString() + b ? 1 : -1);
}
input.forEach(item => {
  let res_1 = big_number_simplified(item.test).join('');
  if (res_1 === item.res) {
        console.log(`[${item.test.join(',')}]: "${res_1}"`);
  } else {
    console.error(`ERROR: [${item.test.join(',')}]: "${res_1}", expected: "${item.res}"`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you combine the numbers they produce a number with the same number of digits.  This means you want to sort them to put the biggest digits first.  In fact this is to opposite problem of sorting numbers inside a string because you want to sort the numbers like you would Strings (from the first digit first)

```
int[] a = {90, 91, 89, 999};
long num = Long.parseLong(
        IntStream.of(a)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                // reverse sort them as Strings.
                .sorted((x, y) -> (y + x).compareTo(x + y))
                .collect(Collectors.joining()));
System.out.println(num);
```

prints

```
999919089
```

Comment: Not sure. With `int[] a = {9, 90};` it prints `909`, but it should print `990`. I think we need a Radix-Sort-like effect.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade and that is why Janos had the right idea in that regard. Thank you.