# How to find the largest possible number given an array of non-negative numbers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

**Problem Statement:** 
I have an array of non-negative numbers in form of String in Java, I want to arrange the integers to form the largest possible number.

**Example:** Given below input:

```
String[] numbers = {"15", "9", "62", "34"};
```

The arrangement "9623415" gives the largest number.

**Note:** I understand we can sort all numbers in descending order, but simply sorting doesn’t work. For example, 15 is larger than 9 in natural order but "9" comes before "15" in the solution. What's the best way to implement a custom comparator in this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Turn them into Strings, then sort, then concatenate.

Comment: @Thilo They already are strings, which makes it trivial...

Comment: Basically, `Arrays.stream(numbers).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(""))`.

Comment: In your comparator, you need to compare based on the first digit/character that should be enough to solve this problem.

    public int compare(String s1,String s2){
    return (s1.charAt(0)-s2.charAt(0));
    }

Let's take the same example here-

we have "15", "9", "62", "34" and now sort this string based on the first digit of array element then the order will be

9> 6>3>1

now arranged the string in same order based on first string as mentioned above-

"9", "62", "34","15"

and finally, append the string that will be your result.

Comment: @Kanahaiya:  Just post an answer next time.

Comment: @Thilo:  That's...um...that was almost *not* a dupe because the other question refers to ints instead of strings, but I can get on the same page there...

Comment: @Kanahaiya There is an extra twist here, though, see the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35759828/14955:  We need to sort `9` after `90` so that we get `990` instead of `909`. The pure lexicographic sort does not do that.

Answer (score -1):

the method `public int compareTo(String anotherString)` of a `String` is what you need which gives you the order of the String **lexicographically** .

**Update1:**
What is lexicographic ordering.

Frome Java Doc:

> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:
>
> this.length()-anotherString.length()

So String `9`will appear ahead of  String `15` in a lexicographic ordering, since they have different characters at index `0`, and char `9` is larger than char `1`. If you read about lexicographic ordering carefully you will find that that order is just what the OP needs!

**Update2:** Why lexicographic ordering is the key for this question

The lexicographic order of the Strings in the question is like this:

`"9", "62", "34","15"`

So after you get this order, the question should be trival: just iterate the ordered sequence and you get the answer.

**Update 3:** How to handle special case like: `"9"&"90"`, since we need `"990"` instead of `"909"`

In this case the lexicographic ordering will fail. But it is easy to figure out a fix:

Instead of `str1.compareTo(str2)`, we can use `(str2+str1).compareTo(str1+str2)`. The key here is to ensure these two strings have at least a bit of different digit, so we don't get the order by comparing there lengths.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is all about a mis-understanding as to how Strings sort, and this answer addresses that.

Comment: Not really, no.  This doesn't explain what "lexicographic" order is or why that addresses the OP's chief concerns with how the ordering will come out in the end.  You may be *right* but you need to do *more* to convince them of it.

Comment: OK I wil post a detailed update..

Comment: There is an extra twist here, though, see the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35759828/14955:  We need to sort `9` after `90` so that we get `990` instead of `909`. The pure lexicographic sort does not do that.