# How to create the smallest number using an int Array.(Number can be long, you can return String instead of number)

Tags: java

How to create the smallest number using an int Array.(Number can be long, you can return String instead of number).

```
Input -->  {10,2,39,37,30,67,7,9}
output --> 1023037396779
```

---

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = new int[]{10, 2, 39, 37, 30, 67, 7, 9};
        ArrayList<String> strArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Integer i : arr) strArr.add(i.toString());
        System.out.println("First sysout");
        strArr.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
        System.out.println("\nsecond sysout");
        Collections.sort(strArr);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        strArr.forEach(e -> sb.append(e));
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the snippet to your post by editing it. It's not readable from the comment section.

Comment: What is the issue you are having and what are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to find the smallest number in an array?

Comment: No. I think what he is trying to do is take each integer in the array and string them together to make the smallest number possible.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm that you are using is wrong. You algorithm fails for `[9, 90]`. `9 < 90` but `990` is not the correct solution. `909` should be the correct solution. You need to arrange the numbers in the array `A` in such a manner that for 2 indices, `i` and `j` such that `i < j`, `A[i] + A[j]` is lexicographically smaller string than `A[j] + A[i]`. To accomplish this you can use custom comparator while sorting.

```java
class LexicographicalSortingOrder implements Comparator<String>
{
    public int compare(String first, String second)
    {
        return (first + second).compareTo(second + first); 
    }
}
```

You can change the line

```java
Collections.sort(strArr)
```

to

```java
Collections.sort(strArr, new LexicographicalSortingOrder())
```

You can also shorten this by using lambda instead of this

```java
Collections.sort(strArr, (first, second) -> (first + second).compareTo(second + first))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
public String minNumber(int[] numbers) {
    // convert int[] -> List<String>
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(numbers.length);
    for (int num : numbers) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(num));
    }

    // sort using custom comparator
    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> (o1 + o2).compareTo(o2 + o1));

    // join sorted items, forming max possible number
    return String.join("", list);
}
```

Or Java8:

```
public String minNumber(int... numbers) {
    return Stream.of(numbers)
            .boxed()
            .filter(n -> n >= 0)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .sorted((s1, s2) -> (s1 + s2).compareTo(s2 + s1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

---

You need to handle a special case like: `"9"&"90"`, since we need `"909"` instead of `"990"`.
In this case `Collections.sort()` will fail. So we need a customized `Comparator`in which we can use `(str1+str2).compareTo(str2+str1)`.

The key here is to ensure these two strings have at least a bit of different digit, so we don't get the order by comparing there lengths.

---

Reference a similar question:

[How to find the largest possible number given an array of non-negative numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53789433/how-to-find-the-largest-possible-number-given-an-array-of-non-negative-numbers-i/53789461#53789461)